# Submitting Bulk Forms In Django

Tags: python, django

I have 5 different forms in  `forms.py`; the forms are all based off of 1 model. The 5 forms are all displayed on the same html page, so as to allow the user to create or register 5 objects into the DB with 1 single button click.

In the future, I might need to submit 50 forms in a single click. If I were to do this based on the existing code, I would probably need 50 forms in `forms.py` and repeat the registration logic in `views.py` for 50 times.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

**views.py**

```
def register(request):

    form1 = DetailsForm1()
    form2 = DetailsForm2()
    form3 = DetailsForm3()
    form4 = DetailsForm4()
    form5 = DetailsForm5()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form1 = DetailsForm1(request.POST)

        if form1.is_valid():
            form1.save()
        

        form2 = DetailsForm2(request.POST)

        if form2.is_valid():
            form2.save()
  

        form3 = DetailsForm3(request.POST)

        if form3.is_valid():
            form3.save()


        form4 = DetailsForm3(request.POST)

        if form3.is_valid():
            form3.save()


        form5 = DetailsForm5(request.POST)

        if form5.is_valid():
            form5.save()

        

        return render(request, "app/registration_completed.html")


    context = {
        "form1": form1, 
        "form2": form2,
        "form3": form3,
        "form4": form4,
        "form5": form5  
    }
    return render(request, "app/register.html", context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class DetailsForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = (
           'owner',
           'address',
           'postcode',
            )

 class DetailsForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = (
           'owner',
           'address',
           'postcode',
            )
   
  class DetailsForm3(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = (
           'owner',
           'address',
           'postcode',
            )
   
  class DetailsForm4(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = (
           'owner',
           'address',
           'postcode',
            )
    
   class DetailsForm5(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = (
           'owner',
           'address',
           'postcode',
            )
```

Comment: Why would you define five form classes that are all the same?  You only need multiple _instances_ of the one form class. But also Django provides an abstraction for this use case called a FormSet, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/formsets/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Comment: If you use a formset, you can look up the JS which allows one to create extra forms in the browser as needed. The other main advantage of a formset is its error handling when one of the N forms is invalid. Worth the slightly steep learning curve for something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple forms in the forms.py, and instead you could do something like this:

```
def register(request):

    form1 = DetailsForm()
    form2 = DetailsForm()
    form3 = DetailsForm()
    ...

    if request.method == "POST":
        form1 = DetailsForm(request.POST)

        if form1.is_valid():
            form1.save()
        

        form2 = DetailsForm(request.POST)

        if form2.is_valid():
            form2.save()
  

        form3 = DetailsForm(request.POST)

        if form3.is_valid():
            form3.save()

        ...        

        return render(request, "app/registration_completed.html")


    context = {
        "form1": form1, 
        "form2": form2,
        "form3": form3,
        ...
    }
    return render(request, "app/register.html", context)
```

with one form defined as in:

```
class DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = (
           'owner',
           'address',
           'postcode',
            )
```

You can optmize the process further if you have so many forms using some loops and lists as follows:

```
def register(request):
   forms = []
   for i in range(30):
      forms.append(DetailsForm())

   if request.method == "POST":
      for form in forms:
         form = DetailsForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

(and continue the rest of the code with the same method of looping through the forms)

Another solution could be using Formsets as mentioned by Anentropic in his comments. However I find the mention I mentioned a bit easier to implement and understand (at least personally)

Comment: You will need to instantiate each form with a different `prefix` so each can pick up its own data `request.POST`.

Comment: @nigel222 I see, I will look into it and improve the answer. Cheers and thank you for the information!